# Maven Error: Failed to execute goal on project,Could not find artifact com.tngtech.java:config-builder

Tags: maven

I'm facing the below issue while pom.xml compiles.

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T17:27:3
    7+05:30)

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ui-test: Could not resolve dependencie
s for project com.siemens.fossology.test:ui-test:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not fin
d artifact com.tngtech.java:config-builder:jar:1.4-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

Ideas on where my problem is?

Comment: post your pom, please

Comment: corrected typo in title

Answer (score 0):

We can see on the internet maven repository http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.tngtech.java/config-builder that there is no config-builder library version 1-4-SNAPSHOT. 
You must downgrade your version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.tngtech.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-builder</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

So with your pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.siemens.fossology.test</groupId>
<artifactId>ui-test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>ui-test</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <main.class>com.siemens.fossology.test.ui.StartUp</main.class>

    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <config-builder.version>1.3</config-builder.version>
    <testng.version>6.1.1</testng.version>
    <guava.version>18.0</guava.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
    <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
    <mockito.version>1.10.8</mockito.version>
    <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
    <selenium-java.version>2.43.1</selenium-java.version>
    <xml-apis.version>1.4.01</xml-apis.version>

    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>2.5</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    <maven-assembly-plugin.version>2.4</maven-assembly-plugin.version>
    <maven-shade-plugin.version>2.3</maven-shade-plugin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tngtech.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>config-builder</artifactId>
        <version>${config-builder.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>${testng.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium-java.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>${xml-apis.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.2.201409121644</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>org/xmlsoap/schemas/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>org/apache/ws/commons/schema/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-assembly-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-shade-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.tooling</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <shadedClassifierName>with-dependencies</shadedClassifierName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you please suggest me which version of Maven i can use to avoid this error.

Comment: I will post my pom.xml also, as because of formatting issue in posting section still not put.

Comment: Can anybody help me how i can proceed.

Comment: To put xml on Stackoverflow just select your code, click on the html button/tab and select {}

Comment: Can you help me how and where i have to update this jar file.

Comment: Just post your pom even if it isn't in the good form and i'll edit it.

Comment: Sure CoDel. Few minutes i will add. But it is telling " it looks like your post is mostly code : please add some more details. I will try again.

Comment: Just put code on yout post, select it, and click the "{}" button

Comment: CoDel i am trying from past 2 hours not able to put pom.xml code. Facing same issue. Is there any way i can send the file to your mail id. Because it helps me to solve the issue.

Comment: Ok, just edit your post and put your pom without trying to format it, i'll fix it for you... Or try to post it as an answer

Comment: Codel thanks for your perseverance. I have put my ppom.xml code in answer. Tell me how i can correct.

Comment: Perfect ! Can you validate the answer please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

            <groupId>com.siemens.fossology.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>ui-test</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>

            <name>ui-test</name>
            <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

            <properties>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

                <main.class>com.siemens.fossology.test.ui.StartUp</main.class>

                <java.version>1.7</java.version>
                <config-builder.version>1.3</config-builder.version>
                <testng.version>6.1.1</testng.version>
                <guava.version>18.0</guava.version>
                <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
                <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
                <mockito.version>1.10.8</mockito.version>
                <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
                <selenium-java.version>2.43.1</selenium-java.version>
                <xml-apis.version>1.4.01</xml-apis.version>

                <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
                <maven-jar-plugin.version>2.5</maven-jar-plugin.version>
                <maven-assembly-plugin.version>2.4</maven-assembly-plugin.version>
                <maven-shade-plugin.version>2.3</maven-shade-plugin.version>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.tngtech.java</groupId>
                    <artifactId>config-builder</artifactId>
                    <version>${config-builder.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                    <version>${testng.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                    <version>${guava.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <version>${logback.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${logback.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
                    <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                    <version>${mockito.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                    <version>${selenium-java.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                    <version>${xml-apis.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>0.7.2.201409121644</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </execution>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>report</id>
                                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>report</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                            <configuration>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org/xmlsoap/schemas/**</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org/apache/ws/commons/schema/**</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>${java.version}</source>
                            <target>${java.version}</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-assembly-plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-shade-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>shade</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <transformers>
                                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                            <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                                        </transformer>
                                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                            <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                        </transformer>
                                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                            <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                        </transformer>
                                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                            <resource>META-INF/spring.tooling</resource>
                                        </transformer>
                                    </transformers>
                                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                                    <shadedClassifierName>with-dependencies</shadedClassifierName>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </project>
```